# Combining a PHP template with a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a page builder that wont let me insert PHP code (only HTML). But it will accept shordcodes.

As I want to include a whole custom post type area, I'm trying to add the custom post type loop inside a separate file and use a shortcode to display the code inside this file. The file I want to include is called team.php and from the directory, is located /inc/team.php

I found this code snippet on another post to add to my functions file and I have added my file name and adjusted the file directory as per commented instructions.

```
add_shortcode('include', 'include_php_file');
function include_php_file($atts=array(), $content='') {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'file' => ''
    ), $atts);
    if(!$atts['file']) return 'team.php'; // needs a file name!
    $file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/'.$atts['file']; // adjust your path here
    if(!file_exists($file_path)) return '';
    ob_start();
    include($file_path);
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

Making the shortcode: `[include file='team.php']` (I think!)...

I was hoping this would be the solution but it doesn't seem to be outputting the code inside my team.php file.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I cant seem to see where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? What does evaluate `file_exists($file_path)` code snippet?

Comment: Also, `return team.php` will _exit the function_, not continue on with using that file name.  That line should be `if(!$atts['file']) { $atts['file'] = 'team.php';}`

Comment: Also, I'd strongly recommend against this style of coding.  Instead, I'd write a function inside your theme that renders the custom post types, and in this shortcode _call that function_.

Comment: Thanks for that line change, Cale_b - It doesn't seem to fix anything - Ill try and look at it with fresh eyes in the morning... Regarding the function that renders the CPT - I don't even know where to start!! Can you point to any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to be the following code:

```
function get_team($atts) {
  ob_start();
  get_template_part('/inc/team');
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('display-team', 'get_team');
```

Works pretty well for me so far, unless anyone has a better solution?